# MSI export in BizTalk has different files than expected

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2016

In BizTalk admin console 2016 there is an option to export the MSI file. I tried to take the backup using this method but after installing the MSI I just compared a schema dll present in the MSI with the DLL in GAC and I see the difference in timestamp and the file also. As per my understanding the DLLin GAC will be part of the MSI export.

So I wanted to know from which path does export MSI functionality takes the backup of files?

Comment: Did you Install *and* Import?

Comment: Yes. After installation i had Gaced the DLL. So it was not matching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Export MSI uses copies of the DLLs stored in the BizTalk database, not the GAC.   If someone has followed bad practices and either GACed a DLL without importing it, or imported it with GACing, then the two will be different, which can cause all sorts of weird problems.

It also causes problems if you attempt to do a roll-back using an exported MSI as it then uses the DLL from the MSI to both import to the BizTalk Databases and the GAC, and if the GAC version was different, then you are not back to your original state.

Comment: Thanks!!.  As you said it is stored in table i got this link(https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/22940.biztalkmgmtdb-all-table-details.aspx) about the tables used. Even though files are stored in tables , application runtime will pick files from GAC only right? Can you please confirm.

Comment: @Navaneet Yes, the runtime uses the DLLs from the GAC, but to find certain objects it uses those from the database, hence you can get weird results if the two are not the same